# Is it possible to create a custom channel using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, anaconda, google-cloud-storage

I would like to [create a custom channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html) but instead of using the local file system, use a GCS bucket to host the packages. I have not been able to find any documentation or resources that indicate whether this is possible and/or how to do it. Does Anaconda allow the indexing of a GCS bucket?

Comment: I absolutely don't know Conda. But if Conda can write in a local file system, try to use [gcsFuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse). Thanks to it, you mount a directory which represent your bucket. GCS fuse transform the system file IO call to GCS API call (take care, these calls aren't free. If you perform a large number of call, it will cost, a little!)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, this appears to work. If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Need-help, done and I added another caveat about the read/write performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Conda can write in a local file system, try to use [gcsFuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse).

Thanks to it, you mount a directory which represent your bucket. GCS fuse transforms the system file IO call to GCS API call. Be careful, these calls aren't free. If you perform a large number of call, it will cost, a little!

In addition, don't expect the same read/write performance as you can have local SSD storage. Here, it's API Call, and the latency is not null!

Thereby, it's transparent for Conda and you can use your bucket like this.